# List with system background color gets messed up in dark mode

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios-darkmode, swiftui-list

I am trying to set a background color for a List that will adapt to the iOS mode (light/dark).
I use .systemGray5 without problems in VStacks but when using it in Lists and I change to dark mode I get a very dark, almost black color which makes everything unintelligible.

This happens regardless if the list is dynamic or static. Is this a bug? Or is there an alternative way to do it?

```
    List {
        Text("Privacy").foregroundColor(Color(.systemRed))
    }.colorMultiply(Color(.systemGray5))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `colorMultiply` will multiply all colors in the list (text, background, separator) with the given color (see [multiply color blending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Multiply)). This will darken the whole view, which probably looks okayish in light mode, but is the opposite of what you want to do in dark mode.

There are two ways to change the background colors in a List:

```
List {
    Text("Privacy").foregroundColor(Color(.systemRed))
        .listRowBackground(Color(.systemGray5))
}
.background(Color(.systemGray5))
```

`background` will change the background of the whole List, but I guess this is only really visible in grouped lists, since the cells usually don't have any space between them.

`listRowBackground` changes the background color of a view when it's used in a List environment. That's probably what you want to use here.

Comment: ok, so this helped with static lists, but dynamic lists still apply no system gray color.
As soon as I write something like this: `List(pumpData) { pump in` the list applies no gray color

Comment: Are you applying the `listRowBackground` to the View that you create _inside_ the `List() { ... }` block?

Comment: This is my non-working code: `List(pumpData) { pump in
                    Text("pump").listRowBackground(Color(.systemGray5))
                }.background(Color(.systemGray5))`

Comment: I provided another answer with my workaround for this seeming bug..

Answer (score 0):

Frank Schlegel provided an answer which works only for static lists. Until Apple fixes this for dynamic lists I solved my problem by using this code

```
List {
    ForEach(pumpData) { pump in
        Text("pump").listRowBackground(Color(.systemGray5))
        }
    }.background(Color(.systemGray5))
```

Answer (score 0):

`.secondarySystemGroupedBackground` worked for me.